# Passing Class.Type into a function Swift

Tags: swift, design-patterns, architecture, overriding, factory-pattern

Working on an override system for a project that has one core codebase, installed in client projects with a submodule, with client specific files and overrides living in the their respective projects.

It's a bit of a convoluted setup, but there are business reasons for setting up the architecture in this way - i.e. we need to make updates to the core project and at the same time allow client to make changes to specific view, controllers, models - so we need as much flexibility on a client-by-client basis.

I've built an override system with the factory pattern that is 99% there. When I need an object I instantiate it by calling:

```
let factory = Factory()    
let object = try factory.getObject(named: "MyObject", ofType: MyObject.self)
```

If an override exists, the factory will instantiate the override (example: override_MyObject), otherwise it will instantiate the default (MyObject). Now I'm just stuck on type-casting these AnyObjects inside the Factory so that they are able to run init(). In this code, I've passed a generic type "T" but I am unable to cast from getInstance with T here:

```
let object = try getInstance(name: named) as? T
```

T is a generic type, and doesn't have the init() method that instances of MyObject do. And Swift won't allow me to pass in MyObject.self and reference that param in the as? casting statement.

Here's the full source code in a playground. It is working right now completely because I am saying as? MyObject.Type instead of using the T to cast the object. I need to be able to use the type I pass into the getObject function to cast the object that comes back from getInstance.

HELP! Any help greatly appreciated.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

protocol TestProt {
    func testMe() -> String
}

@objc(MyObject)
class MyObject: NSObject, TestProt {
    func testMe() -> String {
        return "Hello from Base"
    }
    required override init() {

    }
}

@objc(override_MyObject)
class override_MyObject: MyObject {
    override func testMe() -> String {
        return "Hello from Override"
    }
    required override init() {

    }
}

class Factory {

    let overridePrefix: String = "override_"

    private func getInstance(name: String) throws -> AnyClass {

        do {
            let object = try checkOverride(name)
            return object
        } catch {
            throw FactoryError.defaultError
        }

    }

    public func getObject<T>(named: String, ofType: T.Type) throws -> AnyObject {
        do {
            let object = try getInstance(name: named) as? MyObject.Type
            if let dynamicObject = object?.init() {
                dynamicObject.testMe()
                return dynamicObject
            } else {
                throw FactoryError.defaultError
            }
        }
        catch {
            throw FactoryError.defaultError
        }
    }

    func checkOverride(_ className: String) throws -> AnyClass {

        let overrideClassName = overridePrefix + className

        if let object = NSClassFromString(overrideClassName) {
            print("\(overrideClassName) does exist")
            return object

        } else if let object = NSClassFromString(className) {
            print("\(className) does exist")
            return object

        } else {
            print("\(overrideClassName) does not exist")
            throw FactoryError.defaultError
        }
    }

    enum FactoryError: Error {
        case defaultError
    }

}

let factory = Factory()
let object = try factory.getObject(named: "MyObject", ofType: MyObject.self)
object.testMe()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure really what are you trying to achieve, but consider re-evaluating your solution, it is really bad code. if this is what you are trying to achieve then this might be your solution below.

```
public func getObject<T: MyObject>(named: String, ofType: T.Type) throws -> AnyObject {
    do {
        let object = try getInstance(name: named) as? T.Type
        if let dynamicObject = object?.init() {
            dynamicObject.testMe()
            return dynamicObject
        } else {
            throw FactoryError.defaultError
        }
    }
    catch {
        throw FactoryError.defaultError
    }
}
```

Comment: The objects are dynamic types, so I can't specify MyObject in the declaration. 

My objective is to be able to dynamically init() any object with either its base class, or if it exists, the override. So it needs to work with Views, ViewControllers, Models, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add init to your protocol? it drastically simplifies things and the code is the same for any Type.

```
protocol TestProt {
    init()
    func testMe() -> String
}

class Factory {

    static public func getObject<T: TestProt>() -> T {
        return T();
    }
}

let object: MyObject = Factory.getObject()
let object: override_MyObject = Factory.getObject()
```

Comment: This works if the caller is aware of needing an override or not. I need the factory to handle that, to control if it returns the override if it exists, otherwise return the base class. So the only way I've been able to figure that out is using the override_prefix variable and then attempting to instantiate a class from string with Obj-C, NSClassFromString. That way I know if the override_ class exists. But then I'm dealing with typecasting issues

Comment: Your classes require the blank init already, so any subclasses are required to have it.

Comment: if you change the protocol with other init params then the subclass also have the init params

Comment: I think we're having a terminology miscommunication... I mean override in the sense of -> if override_MyObject class exists, instantiate that, otherwise instantiate MyObject. Then, in that override class that inherits from MyObject, I can override any functions I need to

Comment: ah...that's an unfortunate setup. I would highly recommend designing things  such that the user is initializing any classes they override, or have a configuration object/singleton they can manipulate

Comment: A serious issue with this approach is it's all or nothing. If the user wants to use the subclass anywhere, they have to use it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Then your views, view controllers and models should have common protocol with init() method. In your case you are forced to have NSObject as your base class.

In the solution below I create a protocol called BaseInitializable which is implemented by the Parent Class. Look at the getObject method.

```
import UIKit

protocol BaseInitializable: class {
    func testMe() -> String
    init()
}

@objc(Parent)
class Parent: NSObject, BaseInitializable {


    func testMe() -> String {
        return "Hello from Base"
    }

    required override init() {
        super.init()
        print("parent constructor called")
    }

}

@objc(override_Child)
class override_Child: Parent {
    override func testMe() -> String {
        return "Hello from Override"
    }

    required init() {
        super.init()
        print("child constructor called")

    }
}

@objc(override_Cousin)
class override_Cousin: Parent {
     override func testMe() -> String {
        return "Hello from cousin Override"
    }

    required init() {
        super.init()
        print("cousin constructor called")

    }
}

class Factory {

    let overridePrefix: String = "override_"

    private func getInstance(name: String) throws -> AnyClass {

        do {
            let object = try checkOverride(name)
            return object
        } catch {
            throw FactoryError.defaultError
        }

    }

    public func getObject<T: BaseInitializable>(named: String, ofType: T.Type) throws -> AnyObject {
        do {
            let object = try getInstance(name: named) as? BaseInitializable.Type
            if let dynamicObject = object?.init() {
                dynamicObject.testMe()
                return dynamicObject
            } else {
                throw FactoryError.defaultError
            }
        }
        catch {
            throw FactoryError.defaultError
        }
    }

    func checkOverride(_ className: String) throws -> AnyClass {

        let overrideClassName = overridePrefix + className

        if let object = NSClassFromString(overrideClassName) {
            print("\(overrideClassName) does exist")
            return object

        } else if let object = NSClassFromString(className) {
            print("\(className) does exist")
            return object

        } else {
            print("\(overrideClassName) does not exist")
            throw FactoryError.defaultError
        }
    }

    enum FactoryError: Error {
        case defaultError
    }

}

let factory = Factory()
let object = try factory.getObject(named: "Child", ofType: Parent.self) 
object.testMe()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the solution below where NSObject extended with the BaseInitializable protocol

```
import UIKit

protocol BaseInitializable: class {
    func testMe() -> String
    init()
}

extension NSObject: BaseInitializable {
    internal func testMe() -> String {
        return "test me on extension"
    }
}

@objc(Parent)
class Parent: NSObject {

    override func testMe() -> String {
        return "Hello from Base"
    }

    required override init() {
        super.init()
        print("parent constructor called")
    }

}

@objc(override_Child)
class override_Child: Parent {
    override func testMe() -> String {
        return "Hello from Override"
    }

    required init() {
        super.init()
        print("child constructor called")

    }
}

@objc(override_Cousin)
class override_Cousin: Parent {
     override func testMe() -> String {
        return "Hello from cousin Override"
    }

    required init() {
        super.init()
        print("cousin constructor called")

    }
}

class Factory {

    let overridePrefix: String = "override_"

    private func getInstance(name: String) throws -> AnyClass {

        do {
            let object = try checkOverride(name)
            return object
        } catch {
            throw FactoryError.defaultError
        }

    }

    public func getObject<T: BaseInitializable>(named: String, ofType: T.Type) throws -> AnyObject {
        do {
            let object = try getInstance(name: named) as? BaseInitializable.Type
            if let dynamicObject = object?.init() {
                dynamicObject.testMe()
                return dynamicObject
            } else {
                throw FactoryError.defaultError
            }
        }
        catch {
            throw FactoryError.defaultError
        }
    }

    func checkOverride(_ className: String) throws -> AnyClass {

        let overrideClassName = overridePrefix + className

        if let object = NSClassFromString(overrideClassName) {
            print("\(overrideClassName) does exist")
            return object

        } else if let object = NSClassFromString(className) {
            print("\(className) does exist")
            return object

        } else {
            print("\(overrideClassName) does not exist")
            throw FactoryError.defaultError
        }
    }

    enum FactoryError: Error {
        case defaultError
    }

}

let factory = Factory()
let object = try factory.getObject(named: "Cousin", ofType: Parent.self) 
object.testMe()
```